# How do you debug inability to delete a Namespace after ip netns add test

Tags: linux, mount, linux-kernel, namespace

```
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=9430)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=401072k,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/netns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=401076k,mode=755)
nsfs on /run/netns/test type nsfs (rw)


root@localhost:~# ip netns delete test
Cannot remove namespace file "/var/run/netns/test": Device or resource busy
root@localhost:~# umount --force /run/netns/test 
umount: /run/netns/test: not mounted


netns       20            root  cwd       DIR               8,17     4096          2 /
netns       20            root  rtd       DIR               8,17     4096          2 /
netns       20            root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/20/exe


root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   06:11   0:00 [netns]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:11   0:00 [khungtaskd]
```

What do I do to  fix this? It looks like `netns` is the only user of that mountpoint? Should/Can I kill the thread?

Comment: I recently encountered this problem.  I solved it by rebooting.  But later, I realized that I may have created a WireGuard interface in the permanently "busy" network namespace, and then moved that WireGuard interface to a different namespace.  However, a WireGuard interface, by design, will always use the network namespace of its creation.  I believe this may be true of all TUN interfaces.  I have no idea how to diagnose where TUN interfaces were created.

Comment: I ran into the `Device or resource busy` problem again.  This time I was able to remove the "busy" namespace file by deleting all my WireGuard interfaces (rather than by rebooting).  Perhaps there is some way to identify which WireGuard interface (or interfaces) was causing the problem.  But it was simpler just to delete them all.

Answer (score 1):

Check which process is using the namespace with `fuser`

```
fuser /var/run/netns/test
```

It will output a list of numbers that represent the process IDs that are using that resource.  Each process ID can then be checked using the `ps` command:

```
ps -p 123
```

Comment: it's a kernel process/thread [netns] by the look of it.. and fuser does the same thing as lsof.  fuser /var/run/netns/test --> returns nothing